# Followed Brad Traversey' "Create VScode extension", yet it never shows in my extensions

Tags: html, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If anyone could please help.

I followed Brad Traverseys code step for step, yet I can't see it in my extentions no matter what I do.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srwsnNhiqv8
This was in the video, I did it. So I've ensured all which needed " " were enclosed with these. I moved the file into the .vscode/extensions file and restarted vscode. 
So 'i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I'd really appreciate help on this as it seems hard to search for answers on this.

And just for clarity, I made an HTML CODE SNIPPETS file.

Thanks in advance 
Nick

Comment: What is the need for an HTML snippet file for extension development? Did the extension run in development mode through `Launch`? What did you copy to the extensions directory and which directory (full path with username replaced)

Comment: watched the video: you make a snippet only extension

Comment: C:\ user.name \ .vscode \ extensions \    - that's the directory I put it in, however I'm not sure how to open in dev mode through launch, is there a shortcut or a certain way in which to run it in this way?

Comment: Launch: read the VSC doc page about extension development.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I figured out the issue. So the issue was that there was no publisher in the name. Going through the setup, the difference between the yo code setup I was given vs the setup Brad went through is that he was given a publisher field to apply, I was not given this option. Once I included this in my JSON file and applied it to my extensions name, it appeared, weird but that's what it was. Thanks again for your help though